# Return Function Type in Swift with no parameters

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function displayForPhone and displayForPrinter which does not have any parameters. I want to return those functions from another function called "display". I have the following code in Swift Playground but it just says there is an error but never tells me what the error is:

```
func displayForPrinter() {
    println("Displaying for printer")
}

func displayForPhone() {
    println("Displaying for phone")
}

func display:(shouldDisplayForPhone :Bool)  -> (void) -> (void) {

    return shouldDisplayForPhone ? displayForPhone : displayForPrinter
}
```

Comment: remove the extraneous `:` and void should be Void

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chang your code to this

```
func displayForPrinter() {
    println("Displaying for printer")
}

func displayForPhone() {
    println("Displaying for phone")
}

func display(shouldDisplayForPhone :Bool)  -> (Void) -> (Void) {
    return shouldDisplayForPhone ? displayForPhone : displayForPrinter
}
//test
let function = display(true)
function()
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem! For some reason Swift never told me that I was putting ":" after the function name. I find Swift to be in very immature state right now.

Comment: Well, swift is a new language,it will become better.BTY,if it helps you,please accept my answer

Comment: Yes, I will accept in 1 minute. StackOverFlow restriction :(